# How do I find out which columns and rows contain Extended ASCII codes?

Tags: oracle

Can any one help How to find out which columns and rows  has Extended ASCII Codes in the table  (EX:-Ž,™,Ù)?

Examples

---

jacob\Û

---

=pal®

I need query some thing like Select * from table to get Extended ASCII 
Thanks For help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE mycolumn<>CONVERT(mycolumn, 'US7ASCII');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use TRANSLATE to remove all valid characters from the string, so only the special characters remain. Then check for NULL (as an empty string is NULL in Oracle; don't use length, for the length will not be 0 as one would expect but null):

```
select name
from mytable
where TRANSLATE(name, '®ABCDEFG...abc...', '®') is not null;
```

You will have to put all valid characters in the string where I simply put '...'.

I used one special character to replace itself as you see, because otherwise the replacement string had to be empty, but empty means null in Oracle and translate doesn't work with null.

(Yes, that empty string is null thing in Oracle is really a nuisance.)